# How to send own protocol packet?

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

I want to send some packets of one protocol (layer 3). I know I should use sk_buff, alloc_skb, dev_queue_xmit, but I don't how to create MAC Header. Could you show me the most basic code which only sends ethernet frame with my data?

Answer (score 1):

See `net/netfilter/xt_TEE.c:tee_tg6` in the linux kernel source code for example. You really just need to `ip6_local_out`, and no need to muck with `dev_queue_xmit`.